# ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to fetch a project to my local computer.

The project is using rails 5.1.4. I am using WSL (Linux on Windows), maybe it could be related.

When I start the server, no matter which page I go, the renderer stops on the first **image_tag** it encounters:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 3):
     9:   <div class="row">
    10:     <div class="col-md-4">
    11:       <figure class="figure">
    12:         <%= image_tag("profile_test", class: "figure-img img-fluid rounded", width: "400", alt: "Anaïs Coletta Coaching")  %>
    13:         <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">test <%= link_to "test", "https://www.test.com/fr/", {class: '', target: :_blank} %></figcaption>
    14:       </figure>
    15:       <div class="row">

app/views/pages/about.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_pages_about_html_erb__4371778765434195141_70186281261780'
```

Do you have any idea of what is causing the error? If not, do you know where I can get more information about the error?

Thanks

EDIT: Just noticed that the problem might be everywhere near assets include: it blocks also on stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag

Controller :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @articles = Article.order("created_at").last(3)
    @articles.reverse!
  end
end
```

Comment: if you delete line 12 is it rendering?

Comment: If I comment all image_tag, stylesheet and javascript it works @NeverBe

Comment: why and js and css? image_tag only

Comment: Please use English punctuations when writing in English.

Comment: Could you please add full server log for the action?

Comment: Here you are @Vasilisa : https://pastebin.com/DnMG002W .

Comment: @sawa I'm sorry, could you show what exactly is wrong with my ponctuation ?

Comment: @LéoColetta, two more questions. In which file do you have line `<li><%= image_tag("titre-rncp", width: "50%", alt: "Titre RNCP certifié", class: "d-block mx-auto rounded mt-3") %></li>`? Where is located `titre-rncp` image and why do you use it without extension (jpg, png, etc)?

Comment: @Vasilisa these line are in app/views/_footer.html.erb and `titre-rncp` image is located under app/assets/image . Why there is a JSON error ?

Comment: I would try to get rid of the `alt` value. Set it to empty just to ensure it's not some weird unicode bug. E.g: `<%= image_tag("titre-rncp", width: "50%", alt: "", class: "d-block mx-auto rounded mt-3") %>`

Comment: And post your controller method too.

Comment: @dan-klasson Alt did not fix the thing, I posted my controller, however the problem is present in any page of my application when I include javascript css or image.

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace as well? I think it's called application trace. The one that includes Rails internals.

Comment: You using `sassc-rails` and if so what version?

Comment: This is want you want https://pastebin.com/bEmfGdGt ? @dan-klasson Also, I use 'sass-rails' but not sure if this is the same as 'sassc-rails'

Comment: Just to try to narrow it down a bit. You could try removing the class argument in your image_tag. Maybe add your `gem` file too.

Comment: Seems to be related to `autoprefixer-rails` that is used by `sass-rails`. If you have an old version of that I'd try updating it.

Comment: @dan-klasson that was it thanks, so how did you knew it was autoprefix ? Also, how can I give you the bounty ?

Comment: From the error and full stack. Lemme add an answer. Edit it afterwards or add comment to what version you had to what you switched to.

Comment: oh and you might have to wait a bit to award the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the full stack you posted it seems to be related to `autoprefixer-rails` gem that is used by `sass-rails` which causes the JSON parsing error when it tries to pre-compile your sass.

If you have an old version of `sass-rails` try to update it

Comment: Thanks, the version of autoprefixer-rails was outdated. After updating to 9.4 it worked.